# Training with multiple GPUs and ModelCheckpoint leads to exception

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, gpu

I'm training a 1D CNN with two GPUs (2xK80) with Keras (TensorFlow as backend).

**The issue I'm having**

The issue is (my guess) that I'm trying to save the model weights of one gpu while the other gpu is in the middle of training (or something like that) so I believe I'm looking for a way to halt the fit process when is done, save weights and than go to next epoch.

**The exception I received**

```
File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2622, in load_weights
    load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, self.layers)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 3103, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    layer_names = [n.decode('utf8') for n in f.attrs['layer_names']]
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/_hl/attrs.py", line 60, in __getitem__
    attr = h5a.open(self._id, self._e(name))
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5a.pyx", line 77, in h5py.h5a.open
KeyError: "Can't open attribute (can't locate attribute: 'layer_names')"
root@algoGpu:/home/gpu_user/SourceCode/voc#
```

The question is
How can I train a model on multiple GPUs and at the same time use ModelCheckpoint to save best epoch's weights?

Comment: whats the question here?

Comment: @NishantSingh "... I'm looking for a way to halt the fit process when is done, save weights and than go to next epoch." but I edited it any way. Now you know how to help me?

Comment: probably u should use a combination of time.sleep(1) inside a while loop which checks a condition

Comment: It would probabyl help if you posted a minimal example that breaks.

Comment: @luk32 I'm getting the exception when I train the model (fit()) with ModelCheckpoint, that's about it. I'm getting this exception with the examples provided with Keras.